# Burn 16bit 44.1kHz audio CD with Ubuntu

Tags: music, cd, burning, brasero

I have some lossless high quality audio files in FLAC format. I want to burn an audio CD-R compatible with most old players. I tried brasero and xfburner, and dragged the files inside. However the result was not playable on old players, but only on new players.

I just found that the result files on the CD are some 32bit, converted to WAV files, generated by the CD Burner. However, as the Red Book standard states, the result should be 44.1kHz, 16bit uncompressed pcm.

How can I burn the CD with 16bit, not 32? Or what is the best way to burn lossless audio cd, compatible to old standard?

Why is this conversion done? Resulted wav files seems smaller than flac files (which is compressed). So, are the resulted files still lossless?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can look at changing things using Audacity. 32-bit to 16-bit is not lossless because you lost 32-16=16 bits.